# Proper understanding of the force implied on the container's wall by the hydrostatic preasure

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, pressure, fluid-statics, boundary-conditions

Imagine we have a container of water in the gravitational field. Then due to the hydrostatic pressure, the force on the face of the container will be greater at the bottom of it. But microscopically, the force is the amount of momentum exchanged by water's particles with the face of the container over a period of time. So if the force is greater at the bottom, it means that either the particles there have bigger momentum or they hit the wall more often.

But if they had a bigger momentum, it would mean that the average kinetic energy of particles is greater. Thus, the temperature is greater. And if the frequency of hitting the wall were greater, then it would mean that the density there is greater. But is it really a case? How could we obtain a thermodynamic equilibrium of water in a container with gradients in temperature or/and gradients in density?

Where is the contradiction in that thinking? What should be the proper understanding of the microscopic consideration of the force applied on the container's wall in that case?

Comment: Please clarify what contradiction you're referring to. As you note, the pressure increases with increasing depth in a gravity field. You haven't explained why this is a problem for thermodynamic equilibrium. Uniform pressure is an equilibrium condition only for a constant depth/height.

Comment: The contradiction is that in the equilibrium we shouldn't have gradients in temperature and density but the reasoning I presented leads to such gradients.

Comment: This is incorrect; equilibrium in a gravity field involves a vertical density gradient. See [hydrostatic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium).

Comment: Ok, this is indeed intuitive that we should have gradients in density. But the formula for the hydrostatic pressure in a liquid $p=\rho g h$ assumes the constant density. Why is this assumption valid for liquids? For gases, we could use the state equation to find the relation between density and pressure and integrate it to find the hydrostatic pressure. The microscopic consideration of the force on the wall I presented (if it's correct) reveals the need for varying density, so why the assumption of constant $\rho$ is valid?

Comment: You don’t have to take the density as constant for a liquid if you don’t wish. Have you calculated (or looked up) the maximum possible change in density for Earth’s oceans, for example? Is the rate of change important for everyday applications?

Answer (score 0):

The microscopic cause of pressure is the repulsion between the electronic shells of the neighbouring molecules. The kinetic energy is important to distribute the pressure, to assure that for a given height the same pressure is present in the liquid.

If we fill a container with sand, there will be also pressure on the walls, in spite of the grains are static. The difference is the presence of shear stresses, and the function pressure x height is not pure and linear as in a liquid.

There is pressure in the depths of the oceans, but also in the depths of the Earth crust.